# hbase rowkey design

Tags: nosql, hbase

I am moving from mysql to hbase due to increasing data.

I am designing rowkey for efficient access pattern.

I want to achieve 3 goals.

1. Get all results of email address
2. Get all results of email address + item_type
3. Get all results of particular email address + item_id

I have 4 attributes to choose from

1. user email
2. reverse timestamp
3. item_type
4. item_id

What should my rowkey look like to get rows efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the equivalent SQL fulfill your goals?

Comment: select * from table where email = "xyz" and item_type=2 order by ts desc...I have unique key index on (email, item_type ,item_id)

Comment: Are `email` and `item_type` mandatory in `where` statement? Do you have statements like `select * from table where email = "xyz" ` or `select * from table where item_type=2 `? And you have mentioned you want to "Get all results of particular item_id" in your post. I don't see it from your SQL.

Comment: sorry...email is always there in any query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your main access is by email you can have your main table key as 
email + reverse time + item_id (assuming item_id gives you uniqueness)

You can have an additional "index" table with email+item_type+reverse time+item_id and email+item_id as keys that maps to the first table  (so retrieving by these is a two step process)

Comment: Ok can I keep item_type as column qualifier..Are column qualifier indexed in hbase?

Comment: you can add all the data as column however HBase doesn't really index anything. What it does it store the data lexicographically by the key so it can find it easily but it isn't an index in the database sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are already headed in the right direction as far as concatenated row keys: in any case following comes to mind from your post:

Partitioning key likely consists of your reverse timestamp plus the most frequently queried natural key - would that be the email? Let us suppose so: then choose to make the prefix based on which of the two (reverse timestamp vs email) provides most balanced / non-skewed distribution of your data. That makes your region servers happier.

Choose based on better balanced distribution of records:
   reverse timestamp plus most frequently queried natural key 
     e.g.  reversetimestamp-email
   or email-reversetimestamp

In that manner you will avoid hot spotting on your region servers.
.

To obtain good performance on the additional (secondary ) indexes, that is not "baked into" hbase yet: they have a design doc for it (look under SecondaryIndexing in the wiki).

But you can build your own a couple of ways:

a) use coprocessor to write the item_type as rowkey to separate tabole with a column containing the original (user_email-reverse timestamp (or vice-versa) fact table rowke

b) if disk space not issue and/or the rows are small, just go ahead and duplicate the entire row in the second (and third for the item-id case) tables.